# Problem writting an equation

Tags: equations, errors, compiling, cases, eqnarray

It's me again. I'm trying to write this equation:

[image]

I wrote this way in Latex:

```
\begin{document}           
\usepackage{amsmath}
  
\begin{eqnarray*}   
        (M - I) \cdot v = 0 &\Leftrightarrow& \begin{pmatrix}   
            4 & -6 & -6 \\  
            -1 & 3 & 2 \\   
            3 & -6 & -5  
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}  
            x \\ y \\ z  
        \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  
            0 \\ 0 \\ 0  
        \end{pmatrix} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}  
            4x -6y -6z = 0 \\      
            -x +3y + 2z = 0 \\  
            3x -6y -5z = 0     
        \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \\     
        &\Leftrightarrow& \begin{cases}    
            z = -3y \\    
            x = 3y + 2z \\     
            3x -6y -5z = 0        
        \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}      
            x = -3y \\     
            z = -3y \\      
            0 = 0      
        \end{cases}.          
    \end{eqnarray*}   
\end{document}
```

However, several errors appeared:

[image]

What is the best way to write this equation?

Comment: After moving `\usepackage{amsmath}` before `\begin{document}` and adding `\documentclass{article}` I get no errors from your code.

Comment: as explained on your last question please post example code that shows the problem, not incomplete fragments, and post the error as text not as an image